# Python double forwardslashes when loading instagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, instagram

So I started making an instagram bot that loads in and likes posts follows/unfollows people etc and I came across an issue that I still cannot resolve - when I load into instagram it puts double forward slashes before the username - so it is unable to find it for example https://www.instagram.com//random_user/ and I still cannot figure out why because when it loads into instagram login screen it's fine.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
import os
import time 

class InstagramBot:


    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.base_url = 'https:/www.instagram.com/'
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')

        self.login()

    


   def login(self):
        self.driver.get('{}accounts/login/'.format(self.base_url))

        enter_username = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 
        .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))

    enter_username.send_keys(self.username)
    enter_password = WebDriverWait(self.driver,  
       .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password')))
    enter_password.send_keys(self.password)

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button/div').click()
 

def nav_user(self, user):
    self.driver.get('{}/{}/'.format(self.base_url, user))

    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ig_bot = InstagramBot('lens_queen_photography2', 'randompassword123')


    ig_bot.nav_user('random_user')
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid requesting invalid URLs you can try to use [urlparse.urljoin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) instead of `format`:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

self.driver.get(urljoin(self.base_url, 'accounts/login/'))
```

It was created exactly for this kind of problems